# How to mix Cocos2d-x 3.0 together with my own android game engine?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have make a android game with my own game engine which based on opengles 2.0, now for some reason, it must be use the Cocos2d-x's render combine with my render. In other words, use cocos2d-x draw something, and then use my engine draw other things. So i should mix cocos2d-x 3.0 together with my own game engine.

Because the mid-layer between Cocos2d-x 3.0 and android is NativeActivity, so the first work is make a bridge between cocos2d-x and my java activity. By referring to cocos2d-x 1.0, i finish the work.

Now, I have implemented Cocos2dxActivity, Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView, Cocos2dxRenderer and so on. And use Cocos2dxActivity as my main activity, use Cocos2dxRenderer to render.
Implementation of onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) in Cocos2dxRenderer is:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
    ......
    Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender();
    ......
    myRender();
    ......
}
```

but the result is wrong. When Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender() execute independently, it can render correctly. I don't know the reason, any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide more details: what is happening, what do you expect to happen? Rationale behind the decision may also be good because it sounds like you're straying far off the course here. Maybe what you want is simply a CCNode with custom OpenGL drawing by overriding its draw method?

Comment: Thanks a lot. My aim is to make the cocos2d's scene as part of my game scene. For one example, make all things rendered by cocos2d as background layer, and things rendered by my engine as over layer.

  After calling Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender() and myRnder(),i found the image rendered by cocos2d is just a white grid, affected by some matrix too; but images rendered by my engine show correctly.
  Maybe my shader affects cocos2d's shader, i'm not sure.
  I have check the render part of cocos2d's code, but found nothing.